# Why the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-answer, low-quality

[The Centaur--Let's Get Real, Shall We?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/55663/32097)

**So basically, knowing all this. Can somebody tell me why my answer is at -2, even against the fact, that it highlighted few other problems, and offered a solution to them?**

Comment: I don't understand why you think the OP "snapped". He used all caps on five words to emphasize something. I wouldn't encourage using all caps for anything, but I honestly don't see why it's worth making an entire meta post about.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a rant.

Comment: @apaul34208 But on who?

Answer (score 6):

Alright... I know I shouldn't feed the trolls, but I think this needs to be said...

I voted to close and downvoted this Meta post for being a rant. It doesn't serve a purpose other than stirring the pot and drawing more people and attention to deliberately manufactured drama.

It doesn't appear that anyone "snapped" you engaged with the community the way that you usually do, and as usual it wasn't appreciated.

You seem to have read something into a tiny bit of all caps text which is more than a little surprising given your tendency to overuse it yourself.

Once again people are getting tired of the attention seeking behavior, it may be time to reconsider before you get put in the penalty box again.

Comment: ??? I've already cut that part.

Comment: On the other hand, I seek attention and rep to be finally able to gain back my ability to post questions.

Comment: "Attention seeking" != "Good Reputation."

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that it’s frustrating to work up a detailed answer and have it be not-appreciated.

I also feel for the OP who sees something that indicates that the question was not read and understood properly.